# GRAPE package in GAP cannot create automorphism groups

Tags: graph-theory, computer-algebra-systems, gap

I tried to get the automorphism group of a graph in gap, using the GRAPE package, but I got the following error:

```
Error, the command fail is not a name.
possibly a binary is missing or has not been compiled. called from
Exec( GRAPE_DREADNAUT_EXE, "<", fdre  ); at /[path]/gap4r8/pkg/grape/lib/grape.g:4007 called from
SetAutGroupCanonicalLabellingNauty( gr, setcanon ); at /[path]/gap4r8/pkg/grape/lib/grape.g:4172 called from
SetAutGroupCanonicalLabelling( gr, false ); at /[path]/gap4r8/pkg/grape/lib/grape.g:4218 called from
AutGroupGraph( gamma  ) at /[path]/Downloads/gap4r8/pkg/grape/lib/grape.g:4228 called from
<function "unknown">( <arguments> )
```

This was on a Mac with gap4r8.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out grape was referencing another package - nauty - that hadn't properly compiled.

To fix the problem, I opened "gap/pkg/grape/nauty22" and followed the instructions in the readme that said to run (from the terminal):

```
./configure
make all
```

This produced a file called "dreadnautB", which is what grape needed. To make grape reference this file, I changed line 45, which was originally:

```
GRAPE_DREADNAUT_EXE :=  ExternalFilename(DirectoriesPackagePrograms("grape"),"dreadnautB");
```

to instead read:

```
GRAPE_DREADNAUT_EXE := ExternalFilename(DirectoriesLibrary(""),"pkg/grape/nauty22/dreadnautB");
```

I reloaded gap and grape and the "AutomorphismGroup(gamma)" function worked properly.

Comment: Glad you solved it. Just to check, do you mean that you changed to the `pkg` subdirectory and called `../bin/BuildPackages.sh` as explained at http://www.gap-system.org/Releases/index.html (if you gave GAP 4.8.4), and after that GRAPE was still unusable?